# Unable to retrieve metadata error on add controller process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a MVC Asp.net 5 project. I am using a code-first design. Here is my TrackerModels file.

```
public class TrackerModels : DbContext
{
    public TrackerModels()
        : base("name=TrackerModels")
    {
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ProjectTracker.Models.Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project")]
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    [Required]
    public virtual Project ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is are my connection strings

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ProjectTracker-20171207081108.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjectTracker-20171207081108;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="TrackerModels" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=ProjectTracker.Models.TrackerModels;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am trying to make a controller. See below for the settings I am using.

[Add Controller Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHAGc.png)

But during the auto-generating part is going on I get the following error

[Controller Creation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd5vZ.png)

I've been searching around the forum here but I haven't found an exact match to this error. However even similar issues and their corresponding fixes aren't working for me. This includes adding the Key attributes, DbSet, etc.

Any help would be appreciated along with any good sites/resources that may allow to learn why this happened.

**Update 1**
I refactored my group class to the following but I still get the same error message.

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project{ get; set; }
}
```

**Update 2**
Turns out that I had to restart VS in order for it to not error out with the above fix. This is now working after restarting VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key should be an `int`. Restructure your `Group` class as follows:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    [Required]
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I restructured my code as per your post but I still get the same error message. See the new code in the original post.

Comment: I had to restart VS in order for the error to stop coming up. Your changes did work.